# Method design pattern - Enforce all methods to follow a pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

We are developing a web application and it should allow a person to do certain actions only if they are authorized. So, every method in the controller needs to check if he/she is authorized to execute the particular action(Pls note that permissions are specific to an action). The backend is java and the frontend is javascript.

Something like below,

```
    public class StudentDataInputController {

          public ModelAndView getDataInputView(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
              if (isAuthorized(request)) {
                  // Do something
              }
         }

         public String saveInput(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
             if (isAuthorized(request)) {
                 // Do something
             }
         }
  }
```

I am wondering if there is any design pattern to enforce this for every action defined inside the class. One solution is to define an interface or abstract class and have a dedicated class for every action implementing the interface or extending abstract. But, it will result in a lot of classes and also, I don't think it is feasible given that the return type of every action varies.
Any suggestion will be helpful

Update: Pls note that permissions are specific to an action

Comment: What about putting the authorisation check in the servlet which dispatches requests to these methods (or a servlet filter which checks requests to the servlet(s)). Alternatively you could use an aspect framework to add a check to methods with particular signatures.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for `design-patterns`? Otherwise, what you want to achieve can possibly be done using Aspects like `@Before`.

Comment: Consider using Spring Security to protect your API

Comment: @tgdavies Permissions are specific to an action. Eg: A person can view the data but cannot edit or add data.

Comment: Have the dispatcher check the method it is calling for an annotation which describes the permission check to be performed. If there is no annotation, don't allow the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy Design pattern is probably what your are looking for. To be precise search for `Protection Proxies`.

There are plenty of ways to play with this pattern.

One way is you create a proxy service class for every service class. And inside controllers you hit the proxy object instead of real service class.

Inside your proxies you can decide you wanna hit the service class or not.